# Future's "then" runs even if there's no error to be caught in "catchError"

Tags: dart

**Code:**

```dart
Future<int> _future() async => 1;

void main() {
  _future()
      .catchError((e) => print('catchError = $e'))
      .then((value) => print('value = $value'));
}
```

AFAIK, `catchError` returns a new `Future` and `then` should run after `catchError` has run. But in above code, there's no error and hence `catchError` never runs, however `then` does run. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation for `Future.catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) states:

> Returns a new `Future` that will be completed with either the result of this future or the result of calling the `onError` callback.

Doing `someFuture.catchError(...).then(...)` does not execute the `then` callback *only* if the `catchError` callback fires; it executes the `then` callback when the original `Future` completes *or* if the `onError` callback fires.